# JxBrowser PrintSettings setShrinkToFit Method Missing

Tags: jxbrowser

In a production situation we observed the behavior where certain prints are Shrinking to Fit, when we would like to avoid this and just let the page contents fill the paper that we will want to print from.

We were looking for an option to disable Fit to Paper / Shrink to Fit and found it on some very early versions of JxBrowser.

Here: http://forum.soapui.org/repository/jxbrowser-1.3rc/doc/index.html?com/teamdev/jxbrowser/printing/PrintSettings.html

and Here: http://forum.soapui.org/repository/jxbrowser-1.3rc/demo/src/com/teamdev/xpcom/mozilla/demo/components/PrintDialog.java

I could not find any history or release notes to track down what happened to this setting, or if there is a workaround for it now.

One more thing, is it possible to prompt the Java Printing window/dialog instead of directly printing if it happens to be a javascript print command?

We are using JXBrowser version 6.7.1

Answer (score 0):

The "Fit to Paper / Shrink to Fit" functionality isn't available in JxBrowser Printing API right now. Please send your feature request to JxBrowser team via your account in [Help Desk Center](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/tickets/new).